# Using Serverless Framework to create AWS Lambda Function.Event not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I'm trying out the Serverless Framework to deploy AWS Lambda to process Kafka Messages and write result to Database.
The trigger is Kafka Messages from a SelfManagedKafka cluster and I specify them in serverless.yml

```
frameworkVersion: '1'

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: go1.x
  region: eu-central-1

package:
  exclude:
    - ./**
  include:
    - ./bin/**

functions:
  hello:
    handler: bin/handlerFunc
    vpc:
      securityGroupIds:
        - <Id>
      subnetIds:
        - <subnet1>
        - <subnet2>
        - <subnet3>
    events:
      - kafka:
          topic: my_topic
          consumerGroupId: my_group
          bootstrapServers:
            - host:port
          accessConfigurations:
            saslScram256Auth: <URI to secretsManager>
            serverRootCaCertificate: <URI to secretsManager>
            vpcSubnet:
              - subnet1
              - subnet1
              - subnet1
            vpcSecurityGroup: <Id>
          enabled: true
```

When I deploy this `serverless deploy`, on the AWS Console for Lambda, there's no Trigger configured and no error, no logs.

`serverless deploy` shows warning
`Configuration warning at 'functions.hello.events[0]': unsupported function event`

I'm following the documentation here https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/kafka

and don't understand what I'm missing.

Any suggestions on where/what to look for?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out event type kafka is not supported in SeverlessFramework version 1.

I had to update to version 3 and update the serverless.yml to refere to FrameworkVersion: '3'

And was able to Deploy Lambda with Apache Kafka as Tigger.